# How to you remove multiple apostrophes from filepaths?

Tags: python, regex, directory, apostrophe

My goal is to remove all the single quotes from all file paths in a directory. Working in Windows.

Preamble code:

```
import os
import re

directory = "/home/oem/Documents/test"
```

The following doesn't work.  It deletes the entire file containing an apostrophe.  Also doesn't work to remove `ord` and substitute `"'"`

```
def remove_non_ascii_1(text):

    return ''.join(i for i in text if ord(i) == 39)

[os.rename(os.path.join(dp, f), remove_non_ascii_1(os.path.join(dp, f))) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(directory) for f in filenames]
```

The following works when there is a single apostrophe (ie. file called crazy'yeah.doc changes to crazyyeah.doc.  But it doesn't work when there are multiple apostrophes in the path (ie. crazy'yeah'yeah.doc))

```
def remove_apstrophes(text):

    return re.sub(r"(^.*)(')(.*$)", r"\1\3", text)


[os.rename(os.path.join(dp, f), remove_apstrophes(os.path.join(dp, f))) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(directory) for f in filenames]
```

I tried adding some more capture groups, but this didn't work -  crazy'yeah'yeah.doc remains as is with all apostrophes.

```
def remove_apstrophes(text):

    return re.sub(r"(^.*)(')?.*(')?.*(')?.*(')?.*(.*$)", r"\1\6", text)

[os.rename(os.path.join(dp, f), remove_apstrophes(os.path.join(dp, f))) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(directory) for f in filenames]
```

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: I think I figure it out: `re.sub(r"(^.*)(\')(.*)(\')(.*)(.*$)", r"\1\3\5\6", text)`.  Not super elegant - always happy to have a better solution,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to enforce regex, this code achieves what you're trying to do:

```
def remove_apostrophes(text):
    return text.replace("'", "")
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant code - way better than what I had.

Comment: You're Welcome! Happy to Help!

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your first function by replacing the `==` with a `!=` like so:

```py
def remove_non_ascii_1(text):

    return ''.join(i for i in text if ord(i) != 39)
```

Comment: This is really good - way better than my solution.  Thank you for being so quick.